# Replacing Parameters in REST Requests in Postman from JSON/YAML files

Tags: javascript, json, rest, yaml, postman

My current Problem is: i need to be able to perform the following call:
`https://{Net-IP}:{Net-Port}/rest/devices/{deviceName}.{deviceID}`

First of all defining a host variable such as:
host: `{Net-IP}:{Net-Port}` is not possible.

Second, if i then try to implement the Path-Parameter in the paths such as:
`/devices/{deviceName}.{deviceID}/measurePoints:
    get:
      summary: Method returns list of measure points
      parameters:
        - name: deviceName
          in: path
          type: string
          required: true
          description: device Name
        - name: deviceID
          in: path
          type: string
          required: true
          description: device ID`

then it says Path templating is not allowed.

I need this type of calls to be translated for Postman, i appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make use of [environmental variables/constants etc.](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/environments_and_globals/manage_environments)

Comment: Okay i found out how to make it: i simply take a path variable in the request (you can include only one after a '/') and then i simply map this variable on two environment variables via a pre-request script like this:


`postman.setEnvironmentVariable("pathVariable", environment["environmentVariable1" ]+environment["environmentVariable2"]);`